# Pdf height and width changes when generating file with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to generate pdfs from my website pages. 
To do so, I have an express server that runs Puppeteer and does a couple thing:
- Take the width of the browser when the page was viewed by the user.
- Resize the chrome headless browser.
- Calculate the height of the page.
- Passes the width/height information as parameters to the `page.pdf({})`.

Some of the pages of my websites render finely on one page. But others do render on two pages, as if some elements pushed the content height to be higher than the height calculated in javascript on Puppeteer.

If it does help, I thought I covered my back by using this snippet at the beginning of my code: `await page.emulateMedia('screen');`.

I checked a couple assumptions:
 - Using the debugging console, I got the actual height of the document when resizing the page.
 - I checked that this information was correctly passed to Puppeteer.
 - I checked that the height in inches was the right one by converting it to pixels.

Those three assumptions were right.

Here is my Puppeteer code:

```
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');

    // Resize window to the width it had when the client has seen it.
    async function resizeWindow(width, height) {
      await page.setViewport({height, width});

      // Window frame - probably OS and WM dependent.
      height += 85;

      // Any tab.
      const {targetInfos: [{targetId}]} = await browser._connection.send(
        'Target.getTargets'
      );

      // Tab window.
      const {windowId} = await browser._connection.send(
        'Browser.getWindowForTarget',
        {targetId}
      );

      // Resize.
      await browser._connection.send('Browser.setWindowBounds', {
        bounds: {height, width},
        windowId
      });
    }
    resizeWindow(parseInt(req.body.evidenceWidth), 0); // Use 0 as a default height because it is required, but not relevant.
    // Wait for page width to be actually changed
    await page.mainFrame().waitForFunction(`window.innerWidth === ${parseInt(req.body.evidenceWidth)}`);

    // Go to the page and wait for all the connection on the page to be resolved
    await page.goto(`${req.body.url}`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    // Calculate real page height
    const realPageHeight = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const body = document.body,
            html = document.documentElement;
      const pageHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

      return pageHeight;
    });

    // Convert size from pixel to inches to avoid rounding issues caused by Puppeteer
    const convertPixelToInches = (value) => {
      let inches = Math.ceil(value/ 96 * 1000) / 1000;

      return `${parseFloat(inches).toFixed(3)}in`; // Calculate inches value and round it up.
    }
    const pageWidth = convertPixelToInches(req.body.evidenceWidth);
    const pageHeight = convertPixelToInches(realPageHeight < req.body.evidenceHeight ? req.body.evidenceHeight : realPageHeight);


    // Send the response
    switch(req.body.format) {
      case 'html':
        const html = await page.content();

        await fs.writeFile(join(__dirname, HTML_EVIDENCE_FD, `${uuid}.html`), html, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(`Evidence html could not be generated`, err);
          } else {
            res.status(200).sendFile(join(__dirname, HTML_EVIDENCE_FD, `${uuid}.html`));
          }
        });
        break;

      case 'pdf':
        await page.pdf({
          path: join(__dirname, PDF_EVIDENCE_FD, `${uuid}.pdf`),
          height: pageHeight,
          width: pageWidth,
          printBackground: true,
        });

        res.status(200).sendFile(join(__dirname, PDF_EVIDENCE_FD, `${uuid}.pdf`));
        break;

      default:
        res.status(501).send({ error: 'The format you chose is not supported'});
        break;
    }

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  });

  app.on("listening", function() {
    console.log("Listening on port %d", app.port);
  });
  return app;
```

Also! I noticed another issue, say I have a breakpoint at 750px, and I pass 800px to Puppeteer, I expect that breakpoint to not be hit in my pdf. But the rendering done in the pdf is done as if the page width is under the breakpoint. Is there some invisible margin added during the pdf generation?

Answer (score 3):

So after a couple of days of searching, I found out the issues:

- I used rem for font-size and line-height in css, so I removed them
  fro the incriminated elements.
- I did not have a reset css, adding normalize.css at the top of my
  styles fixed most of my height issues.
- Even with normalize.css, Chrome was adding an rem padding around
  paragraphs, I add to set a value in pixels instead.